# Array inside ArrayList inside Arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

So I am trying to create a program which creates a Computer Cluster which can have one or more racks, each of which can contain one or more nodes, each of which can contain one or two processors, each of which have a certain amount of cores and Hz.

Conceptually, I know what to do. The cluster class has to have an arraylist which contains an arraylist from each rack, which contains an arraylist of each node, which contains an array for each processor. But for the life of me, I can't figure out how to put this into code. I would really appreciate some help and even some example code.

I am not looking for this to be done for me, I am just unsure how to do stacking arraylists. And to be clear, ComputerCluster, Racks, Nodes, and Processors are each their own class, with a main class to be added later.

Comment: Start from the processors and work your way out level by level.

Comment: example for your cluster: `ArrayList<Rack> racks=new ArrayList<Rack>();` then in your rack class `ArrayList<Node> racks=new ArrayList<Node>();` and in your node class: `Processor[] processors=new Processor[2];`

Answer (score 1):

```
class Processor {

  }

class Node {
    ArrayList<Processor> processors = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<Processor> getProcessors() {
        return processors;
    }

    public void setProcessors(ArrayList<Processor> processors) {
        this.processors = processors;
    }
    public void addNode(Processor processor){
       processors.add(processor);
    }

}

class Rack {
    ArrayList<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<Node> getNodes() {
        return nodes;
    }

    public void setNodes(ArrayList<Node> nodes) {
        this.nodes = nodes;
    }
    public void addNode(Node node){
        nodes.add(node);
    }
}

public class ComputerCuster {
    ArrayList<Rack> racks = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<Rack> getRacks() {
        return racks;
    }

    public void setRacks(ArrayList<Rack> racks) {
        this.racks = racks;
    }
    public void addRack(Rack rack){
        racks.add(rack);
    }

}
```

Comment: Could I ask you give a quick run through of how your code works? Since they are all the same, just one class should be enough